# Institute affiliation link in google scholar

Tags: google-scholar, affiliation, hyperlinks

As you may have seen, in google scholar, there is no link for some institutes in the profile page of researchers. I wonder why this is so. After a great deal of searches I figured out that the main reason could be not having a verified email, however it seems to be not. A sample institute without link in profile of its researchers is as follow:
https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=GSK+company&btnG=

I would be grateful if you could help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

A scholar who wants their profile to link to an institute page needs to do two things

1. Include the institution in the profile's affiliation field, and
2. Verify an email address at the same institution.

The only place I've seen these requirements stated is if you go to an institute page ([example](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&org=17378520676242163638)) and click 'Learn more'.

---

Implicit in requirement #2 is that Google Scholar can recognize that the verified email address is related to the affiliation in question. It seems flexible enough with formats for use with university purposes, but maybe not for larger conglomerations. For example, under your link I can find a [profile affiliated with GSK directly](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=t_VK10gAAAAJ) with a verified gsk.com email address where said link shows up. On the other hand, it seems that the system does not recognize that the same email domain is used for GSK's subsidiaries.